# How to rearrange the characters of a font with virtual font

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

My setup: TeX Live
How can I remap slot 39 to slot 13?

I tried to do it by creating a virtual font:

```
tftopl cmtt10.tfm > cmtt10.vpl
patch <<EOF
--- cmtt10.vpl
+++ cmtt10.vpl
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+(MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME cmtt10))
 (FAMILY CMTT)
 (FACE O 352)
 (CODINGSCHEME TEX TYPEWRITER TEXT)
@@ -192,6 +193,7 @@
 (CHARACTER O 47
    (CHARWD R 0.524996)
    (CHARHT R 0.611112)
+   (MAP (SETCHAR O 15))
    )
 (CHARACTER O 50
    (CHARWD R 0.524996)
EOF
vptovf cmtt10.vpl
rm cmtt10.tfm cmtt10.vpl
```

Create test.tex:

```
\tt '
\bye
```

`tex test.tex`

**EDIT**:
Indeed, as `cfr` suggested, there is infinite recursion:

`dvicopy test.dvi expand.dvi`

```
DVI: font 29 = cmtt10.
DVI: font 0 = cmr10.
DVI: processing page 1.
DVI: font 29 = cmtt10.
TFM: font 0 = cmtt10.
VF file: '',
   for font 0 = cmtt10.
VF: font 0 = cmtt10.
 !Infinite VF recursion?
level=10 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=9 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=8 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=7 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=6 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=5 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=4 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=3 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=2 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=1 font = cmtt10 char=13
level=0 font = cmtt10 char=39
 !Sorry, DVIcopy capacity exceeded [recursion=10].
```

Comment: `tftopl` creates `.pl` files. Are you sure you can treat them as `.vpl`? I've made my fair share of virtual fonts but I've never tried to do it this way.

Comment: Also, I would be sceptical about mapping a font X as part of the specification of font X. Is that dangerously circular?

Answer (score 2):

This works as required ( differs from above only by `cmtt10` changed to `mycmtt10`)

```
tftopl cmtt10.tfm > mycmtt10.vpl
patch <<EOF
--- mycmtt10.vpl
+++ mycmtt10.vpl
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+(MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME cmtt10))
 (FAMILY CMTT)
 (FACE O 352)
 (CODINGSCHEME TEX TYPEWRITER TEXT)
@@ -192,6 +193,7 @@
 (CHARACTER O 47
    (CHARWD R 0.524996)
    (CHARHT R 0.611112)
+   (MAP (SETCHAR O 15))
    )
 (CHARACTER O 50
    (CHARWD R 0.524996)
EOF
vptovf mycmtt10.vpl
rm mycmtt10.vpl
```

For portability compile with:

```
tex -jobname test '\font\tentt=mycmtt10 \input test.tex'
```